# PHP Doctrine Many-to-One Bidirectional Mapping

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

i'm using Symfony 2.7 and Doctrine in the latest version.
I tried the many-to-one bidirectional example from their:

http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-bidirectional

Now I can add Products with my Controller, but it doesn't update my features.

Here is the code for the product entity:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/** @ORM\Entity
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="product")
 *
 */
class Product
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Feature", mappedBy="product")
     **/
    private $features;


    public function __construct() {
        $this->features = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function addFeature(Feature $feature)
    {
        return $this->features[] = $feature;
    }

    public function getFeatures()
    {
        return $this->features;
    }

}
```

and the code for feature entity:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;


/** @ORM\Entity
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="feature")
 *
 */
class Feature
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Product", inversedBy="features")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     **/
    private $product;

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getProduct()
    {
        return $this->product;
    }

    public function setProduct($product)
    {
        $this->product = $product;
    }

}
```

In my controller i just create a new product and a new feature and add the feature to my product-entity:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

use AppBundle\Entity\Product;
use AppBundle\Entity\Feature;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/")
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $feature = new Feature();
        $product = new Product();

        $product->addFeature($feature);

        $em->persist($feature);
        $em->persist($product);
        $em->flush();

        return new Response('Created product id '.$product->getId());
    }

}
```

I only get a new Product and a new feature. The feature doesn't get the relation to the product (the product_id field on database contains "NULL").

Comment: Maybe your return in the addFeature ?

Comment: Change `addFeature` to : `$this->features->add($feature)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the `addFeature` method of the `Product` class into

```
public function addFeature(Feature $feature)
{
    return $this->features->add($feature->setProduct($this));
}
```

and change the `setProduct` method of the `Feature` class into

```
public function setProduct($product)
{
    $this->product = $product;

    // For chaining
    return $this;
}
```

If these changes do not solve your problem, try changing the `$features` property annotation into

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Feature", mappedBy="product", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 **/
private $features;
```

The `cascade` option tells Doctrine to automatically manage the sub-entity.

Comment: Thanks to @Matteo 'Ingannatore' G. That works for me.

Comment: @FelixBäder please accept my answer as valid if it works :)